# laravel Eloquent one to many same object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

ok I have this table "areas":

```
id -> primary key, int
parent -> int, index, nullable
areaName -> string
```

this table contains areas, and each area can be a son of another area, so the parent column could be null, or another id of any other area.

now I want to make it accessible with Eloquent, this is an one to many relationship.

I tried this code but not so good, any ideas from someone who done something like this?

```
class Area extends Eloquent {

    public function sons() {

        return $this->hasMany('Area', 'id', 'parent');
    }

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Area');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the solution, it works great for me.

```
class Area extends Eloquent {
    public function subAreas() {
        return $this->hasMany('Area', 'parent', 'id');
    }

    public function parentArea() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Area', 'parent', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong and from the given code, Laravel complains about `area_id` column is not found, am I right?
This happens because you do not provide name of foreign column and Laravel tries to guess it for you.

Change relationship definition to this

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Area', 'parent');
}
```